# NameError: name 'topstory_ids' is not defined

Tags: dagster

I am new to Dagster and trying to follow the tutorial from official documentation, https://docs.dagster.io/tutorial/building-an-asset-graph

After I copied and pasted this code, I got this error. `NameError: name 'topstory_ids' is not defined` How do I define `topstory_ids`?

```
import json
import os

import pandas as pd  # Add new imports to the top of `assets.py`
import requests

from dagster import asset


@asset(deps=[topstory_ids])  # this asset is dependent on topstory_ids
def topstories() -> None:
    with open("data/topstory_ids.json", "r") as f:
        topstory_ids = json.load(f)

    results = []
    for item_id in topstory_ids:
        item = requests.get(
            f"https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/{item_id}.json"
        ).json()
        results.append(item)

        if len(results) % 20 == 0:
            print(f"Got {len(results)} items so far.")

    df = pd.DataFrame(results)
    df.to_csv("data/topstories.csv")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution already. I just need to define `topstory_ids` asset above `topstories`

```
# Define the topstory_ids asset
@asset
def topstory_ids() -> list:
    with open("data/topstory_ids.json", "r") as f:
        topstory_ids = json.load(f)
    return topstory_ids
```